# Loomis-Whitney versus Gagliardo inequalities

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, inequalities

When searching for a reference, I discovered a curious fact about the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loomis%E2%80%93Whitney_inequality) concerning the Loomis-Whitney Inequality (LWI).This page, which exists only in an English version, states that the LWI is
$$\int_{{\mathbb R}^n}\prod_{i=1}^ng_i(\hat x_i)\,dx\le\prod_{i=1}^n\|g_i\|_{L^{n-1}({\mathbb R}^{n-1})},$$
for every measurable functions $g_i\ge0$ over ${\mathbb R}^{n-1}$. The notation $\hat x_i$ for a vector $x\in{\mathbb R}^n$ means that the coordinate $x_i $ is dropped.

It seems to me that Loomis and Whitney ([1949](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1949-55-10/S0002-9904-1949-09320-5/S0002-9904-1949-09320-5.pdf)) did not establish this inequality, which is actually due to Gagliardo ([1958](http://www.mathnet.ru/links/bf7924026167e93e2e3e613a2940174f/mat188.pdf)). They proved instead that if $E$ is a measurable domain of ${\mathbb R}^n$ and $E_i$ denotes its projection under $x\mapsto \hat x_i$, then
$$\mu_n(E)^{n-1}\le\prod_{i=1}^n\mu_{n-1}(E_i).$$
The latter inequality can be viewed as a consequence of the Gagliardo Inequality (GI). But to me, they are not equivalent to each other.

> Is there a way to prove GI, starting from the original LW ?
>
> Although I am a contributor to the French Wikipedia, I don't have rights to modify an English page. Who could correct it ? In particular, it seems important to give full credit to Gagliardo. His inequality is the best starting point in the proof of Sobolev Inequalities.

Comment: I think you can just register on the English Wikipedia and your editing privileges will carry over. (At least that's how it works for me when I occasionally edit pages in other languages). Since the change affects the very title of the page, this will probably require some careful explanation and documentation, it does not look like a simple edit and runs the risk of being quickly reverted if not properly documented.

Comment: As it now stands, the wiki page is completely misleading. In my opinion, one should create a new page titled "Gagliardo's inequality" or something like that, and take there the main content of the present page, and then modify the present page so that it presents the true content of Loomis and Whitney's paper.

Comment: Actually, as given e.g. in Robert A. Adams' *Sobolev Spaces*, Gagliardo's inequality is more general than the one appearing above and in the wiki page which is the particular case where $k=n-1$ in Adams' notation.